# Bug getting data from server to client using MERN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, mern

I'm building a MERN web aplication and I have a bug that when I make a get request in the clinet side I don't get the right data from the server.

This is the controller function from the server for the request GET http://localhost:5000/public_facility/:id

```
export const getPublicFacilityData = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        return res.status(404).json({ message: `No valid public facility id: ${id}`});
    }

    try {
        const result = await PublicFacilityModel.findById(id, 'name data');
        res.status(200).json({result});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Could not get public facility data'});
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

This is what I get using postman or VS REST Client extension with an example id (is the same data that I have in MongoDB):

```
  "result": {
    "_id": "60269642b8f3741a7c6a54ei",
    "name": "TOWN HALL",
    "data": [
      {
        "year": 2019,
        "annual_data": [
          {
            "consumption": [10,10,10]
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Total"
          },
          {
            "consumption": [20,20,20],
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Electricity"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "year": 2018,
        "annual_data": [
          {
            "consumption": [30,30,30],
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Total"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the function I use from the client side to make the request:

```
export const getPublicFacilityDatasets = async (id) => {
    if(id){
        try {           
            const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/public_facility/${id}`);
            
            //console.log('Result: ', res.data); 
            //console.log('Total consumption 2018', res.data.result.data[1].annual_data[0].consumption);
            ...

        } catch (error) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the data I recive doing the request in the client side:

```
{
  "result": {
    "_id": "60269642b8f3741a7c6a54ei",
    "name": "TOWN HALL",
    "data": [
      {
        "year": 2019,
        "annual_data": [
          {
            "consumption": [10,10,10]
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Total"
          },
          {
            "consumption": [20,20,20],
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Electricity"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "year": 2018,
        "annual_data": [
          {
            "consumption": [10,10,10],
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Total"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It looks like the same data that I have in my database but the total consumption in 2018 (`result.data[1].annual_data[0].consumption`) has the values of total consumption in 2019.

I found it very strange that if I do `console.log(res.data)` just before doing the request, `res.data.result.data[1].annual_data[0].consumption` has wrong values `[10,10,10]` but if I do `console.log(res.data.result.data[1].annual_data[0].consumption)` it shows the correct values `[30,30,30]`. It looks like they are not the same object but I don't have any other variable called result.

Does anyone have any ideas? Let me know if I need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question.

The issue it is not related with server request. I use the data that I get to display a chart that has a custom legend to filter the data. The problem is that I stored this data in a state variable and when I modify it (hide/show in the chart) it messes up.

If you are curious, the real issue is that using chart-js-2 every dataset has to have a unique label.

Now it works, but I still don't understand why when I `console.log()` the data it was already wrong. Maybe the return statement and render components were executed before?

Answer (score 1):

result.data - Array.
You are accessing an array object by index, but ordering is optional in arrays. There are several ways to get data from an array on the frontend:

1. Search by array and selection by unique element

```
const getDataByYear = (arr,year) =>{
return arr.find((x)=> x.year===year)
}
getDataByYear(res.data.result.data,2018)
```

2. Normalization of data received from the server and treatment by identifier.In this case, you need to bring the received data to this form:
   array->Object

```
{
  "result": {
    "_id": "60269642b8f3741a7c6a54ei",
    "name": "TOWN HALL",
    "data": {
      "2019": {
        "year": 2019,
        "annual_data": [
          {
            "consumption": [10,10,10]
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Total"
          },
          {
            "consumption": [20,20,20],
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Electricity"
          }
        ]
      },
      "2018": {
        "year": 2018,
        "annual_data": [
          {
            "consumption": [10,10,10],
            "price": [],
            "concept": "Total"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you will access for elements like `result.data[2018].annual_data[0].consumption`

Do not use index access to arrays if you have not found the index of an array element through a separate function and are not sure that a specific element has a specific index.

More info about data normalization : [Redux post](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

**Test Variant**

I test the same scheme on my api, but i use some other code. You can try if you want:

```
export const getPublicFacilityData = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        return res.status(404).send({ message: `No valid public facility id: ${id}`});
    }

    try {
        const result = await PublicFacilityModel.findById(id, 'name data');
        res.status(200).send(result);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Could not get public facility data'});
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

```
export const getPublicFacilityDatasets = async (id) => {
    if(id){
        try {           
            const {data} = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/public_facility/${id}`);

console.log(data)
        } catch (error) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my schema to put an embedded document in ```data``` so I could replace ```data``` and ```annual_data``` arreys to dicitonaies. But I still have the same error. The problem is that the data I recieve from the server is already wrong.

Comment: i change json to send

Comment: @PauCasademont I just got the idea that the problem is in the parser at the reception at axios. I use it myself and look at my api and everything seems to be the same

Comment: The same, but I use send, no json

Comment: I didn't see it at first. I tested with send and still having the same issue